# How to synchronize JMeter Thread groups

Tags: jmeter

I fill the database with JMeter. There is 2 thread groups which fill 2 tables in parallel.
After these 2 tables filled I need to start the last thread group to fill the third table.
How can I do it?
Is it possible to synchronize JMeter Thread groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do a while controller for the third thread group, and do something like this:

ThreadGroup 1
 - Code to fill Table 1
 - Set a UserDefined Variable "Group1_done==true" as the last step

ThreadGroup 2
 - Code to fill Table 2
 - Set a UserDefined Variable "Group2_done==true" as the last step

ThreadGroup 3
 - WHILE CONTROLLER "Group1_done==true"&&"Group2_done==true"
   - Code to fill Table 3