# How to synchronize JMeter Thread groups by using user defined variable

Tags: jmeter

I am inexperienced in JMeter. What I want to do is to synchronize JMeter Thread groups. With respect to ["How to synchronize JMeter Thread groups"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176903/how-to-synchronize-jmeter-thread-groups),  I would like to ask an account of how to 'set a UserDefined Variable `"Group1_done==true"` as the last step'.

I defined user defined variable with initial value but I did not set it value later. How can I set it value in any step?

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

You may set value for variable / property even in HTTP Request Sampler:

[image]

Your while loop will look like:

```
Thread Group 1
    . . .
    . . .
    [execute your test logic here]
    . . .
    HTTP Request
    // last step
    ${__setProperty(group1_done,TRUE,)}
    . . .
```

Condition expression for WHILE cycle in 3rd Thread Group:

```
${__P(group1_done,)} && ${__P(group2_done,)
```