# How to synchronize two thread groups in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

using Jmeter, I want to achieve something like this:

```
Thread Group 1
 - Http Request 1
 - Set P1 to "true"
 - Wait synchronization with Thread Group 2 (parameters P1 and P2 are both "true")
 - Http Request 2

Thread Group 2
 - Http Request 1
 - Set P2 to "true"
 - Wait synchronization with Thread Group 1 (parameters P1 and P2 are both "true")
 - Http Request 2
```

This is essentially the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176903/how-to-synchronize-jmeter-thread-groups) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009144/how-to-synchronize-jmeter-thread-groups-by-using-user-defined-variable) described: I set P1 and P2 to "true" as follows (HTTP Request / BeanShell both work):

```
${__setProperty(P1,"true",)}
```

my problem is how to implement the wait condition. I've tried all the possible combinations for the while controller's exiting condition but couldn't achieve what I want. Strangely, a Debug sampler (or a beanshell with a log.info) placed within the loops shows me the properties P1 and P2 are correctly set (and the exit condition satisfies what I expect), but it doesn't exit anyway. For Example I've tried:

```
${__property("P1")}!="true"||${__property("P2")}!="true"
${__property(P1)}!="true"||${__property(P2)}!="true"
${__property(P1)}=="true"&&${__property(P2)}=="true"
${__property("P1")}=="true"&&${__property("P2")}=="true"
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See this component which handles inter thread communication:

- http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the __BeanShell function for the while condition:

```
${__BeanShell((${__property(P1)}!="true"||${__property(P2)}!="true"}
```

furthermore, the While controller cannot be empty (you have to add a sampler or something like this, otherwise it will be skipped).